# Dynamic number of test cases in genetic programming?

Tags: genetic-programming

When looking at Genetic programming papers, it seems to me that the number of test cases is always fixed. However, most mutations should (?) at every stage of the execution be very deleterious, i. e. make it obvious after one test case that the mutated program performs much worse than the previous one. What happens if you, at first, only try very few (one?) test case and look whether the mutation makes any sense?

Is it maybe so that different test cases test for different features of the solutions, and one mutation will probably improve only one of those features?

Comment: What do you mean by a "test case"? Do you mean "fitness function"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I agree with your assumption that most mutations should be very deleterious, but you shouldn't care **even if they were**. Your goal is not to optimize the individuals, but to optimize the population. So trying to determine if a "mutation makes any sense" is exactly what genetic programming is supposed to do: i.e. eliminate mutations that "don't make sense." Your only "guidance" for the algorithm should come through the fitness function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure what you mean with "test case", but for me it sounds like you are looking for something related to multi-objective-optimization (MOO). That means you try to optimize a solution regarding different aspects of the problem - therefore you do not need to mutate/evaluate a population for a specific test-case, but to find a multi objective fitness function. 
"The main idea in MOO is the notion of Pareto dominance" (http://www.gp-field-guide.org.uk)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea in theory but tricky to put into practice. I can't remember seeing this approach actually used before but I wouldn't be surprised if it has.

I presume your motivation for doing this is to improve the efficiency of the applying the fitness function - you can stop evaluation early and discard the individual (or set fitness to 0) if the tests look like they're going to be terrible.

One challenge is to decide how many test cases to apply; discarding an individual after one random test case is surely not a good idea as the test case could be a real outlier. Perhaps terminating evaluation after 50% of test cases if the fitness of the individual was <10% of the best would probably not discard any very good individuals; on the other hand it might not be worth it given a lot of individuals will be of middle-of-the road fitness and might well only save a small proportion of the computation. You could adjust the numbers so you save more effort, but the more effort you try to save the more chances you have of genuinely good individuals being discarded by accident.

Factor in the extra time to taken to code this and possible bugs etc. and I shouldn't think the benefit would be worthwhile (unless this is a research project in which case it might be interesting to try it and see).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good idea. Fitness evaluation is the most computational intense process in GP, so estimating the fitness value of individuals in order to reduce the computational expense of actually calculating the fitness could be an important optimization.

Your idea is a form of fitness approximation, sometimes it's called lazy evaluation (try searching these words, there are some research papers).

There are also **distinct** but somewhat overlapping schemes, for instance:

- Dynamic Subset Selection (Chris Gathercole, Peter Ross) is a method to select a small subset of the training data set on which to actually carry out the GP algorithm;
- Segment-Based Genetic Programming (Nailah Al-Madi, Simone Ludwig) is a technique that reduces the execution time of GP by partitioning the dataset into segments and using the segments in the fitness evaluation process.

PS also in the Brood Recombination Crossover (Tackett) child programs are usually evaluated on a restricted number of test cases to speed up the crossover.